# How does the sockets communication in Unix work? Is there a special delimiter? What is '\r'?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, unix

My question arises because I am developing a small server using C and sockets with select in a  Linux system. The server receives one character at the time.

Ex: if a client types "hi" and then presses enter, the server will receive h, then i, and finally '\n'.

I heard of '\r' but I can't find any relevant information about it more than what it is but not when it is sent.

The question is: If I wanna execute an action based on the value of the string, should I buffer the data up to the '\n' and then check what it contains? Or should I be looking for a '\r' everytime a character is received?

Comment: Depends on the protocol.  For example, HTTP uses `\r\n` in between lines of the request and response headers

Comment: So in the 'hi' example, would it be 'h', then 'i', then '\r\n'? @BenVoigt

Comment: Yes four characters, `h`, `i`, `\r`, `\n`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on what is being sent over the socket.  The sockets don't care.  What protocol is the server using? *That's* the question. Did it read lines with `gets()`?  From files?  Your client has to know something about the agreement (protocol) being used.

You can use a packet sniffer like wireshark some other way to 'sniff the wire' to see what is being sent from the client. Or just use `read()` as shown below and read a fixed amount and display the ASCII numeric value of what you receive until you determine the line terminator or delimiter you want to divide content up with.

'\r' = carriage return  (ASCII 0x0d)
'\n' = linefeed (ASCII 0x0a)

No big mystery to socket programs.

Here's an example of communicating over sockets in a single program using a pair of sockets retrieved from a socketpair() system call.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define DATA1 "In Xanadu, did Kublai Khan . . ."
#define DATA2 "A stately pleasure dome decree . . ."

/*
 * This program creates a pair of connected sockets, then forks and
 * communicates over them.  This is very similar to communication with pipes;
 * however, socketpairs are two-way communications objects. Therefore,
 * this program can send messages in both directions.
 */
main()
{
    int sockets[2], child;
    char buf[1024];

    if (socketpair(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0, sockets) < 0) {
        perror("opening stream socket pair");
        exit(1);
    }
    if ((child = fork()) == -1)
        perror("fork");
    else if (child) {   /* This is the parent. */
        close(sockets[0]);
        if (read(sockets[1], buf, 1024, 0) < 0)
            perror("reading stream message");
        printf("-->%s\n", buf);
        if (write(sockets[1], DATA2, sizeof(DATA2)) < 0)
            perror("writing stream message");
        close(sockets[1]);
    } else {        /* This is the child. */
        close(sockets[1]);
        if (write(sockets[0], DATA1, sizeof(DATA1)) < 0)
            perror("writing stream message");
        if (read(sockets[0], buf, 1024, 0) < 0)
            perror("reading stream message");
        printf("-->%s\n", buf);
        close(sockets[0]);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's good to note the read() count could be used.  It's obviously not a complete practical example. Just to illustrate some basics and that delimiters don't *need* to be explicitly checked for.